# history.pushState работает некорректно в хроме

Tags: javascript, html

Есть две страницы. Страница с фильтром и страница товара (товары находятся на странице с фильтром).
При выборе чекбокса у фильтра, я прокидываю параметры GET в URL при помощи:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, response.request.responseURL);
```

В `response.request.responseURL`, попадает строка: `localhost:30/shop?tag[]=5`

Здесь все отлично.
Как только я перехожу на страницу товара, со страницы фильтра, и на странице товара нажимаю кнопку "Назад" - страница не прорисовывается, а выводится текст response-a.

в ФФ - все работает как надо. Но в хромах - такая беда. Что нужно изменить?

Comment: попробуйте передавать только: '/shop?tag[]=5'

Comment: Аналогично. Ощущение, что хром какую-то внутреннюю функцию не вызывает, что делает ФФ

Comment: предлагают проверить состояние в истории:   window.history.replaceState( state, state.title || document.title, href );
  //
  //  Check is to make sure that jqm doesn't throw type errors in environments where
  //  window.history is not available (e.g. Chrome packaged apps)
  if ( window.history && window.history.replaceState ) {
   window.history.replaceState( state, state.title || document.title, href );
  }

Comment: @Konst Проверял через ``console.log(history.state)`` - null. Возможно есть другие способы прокидывать гет параметры без перезагрузки на вью :\